# the request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided aws

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to cors upload my video file from browser to Amazon S3 storage via asp.net project. But I keep getting this error:"the request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided"

Here is the javascript code I have;

```
function uploadFile() {

var access_key = "xx";
var secret = "xx";
var policy = "xx";
var signature = "xx";

var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
var fd = new FormData();

var key = "folder1/" + (new Date).getTime() + '-' + file.name;

fd.append('key', key);
fd.append('acl', 'public-read-write');
fd.append('Content-Type', file.type);
fd.append('AWSAccessKeyId', access_key);
fd.append('policy', policy)
fd.append('signature', signature);

fd.append("file", file);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);
xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);
xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

xhr.open('POST', 'https://bucketName.s3.amazonaws.com/', true);

xhr.send(fd);
```

}

Here is the policy string ;

```
{" +
                      "\"Id\": \"Policyxxx\"," +
                      "\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\"," +
                      "\"Statement\": [" +
                        "{" +
                          "\"Sid\": \"Stmtxxx\"," +
                          "\"Action\": \"s3:*\"," +
                          "\"Effect\": \"Allow\"," +
                          "\"Resource\": \"arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/*\"," +
                          "\"Principal\": \"*\"" +
                        "}" +
                      "]" +
                    "}
```

and here is the getsignature method;

```
 public static string GetS3Signature(string policyStr)
    {
        string b64Policy = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(policyStr));

        byte[] b64Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AwsSecretKey);
        HMACSHA1 hmacSha1 = new HMACSHA1(b64Key);

        var c = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b64Policy)));
        return c;
    }
```

What could be the reason for the error

Comment: How are you constructing the signature? It needs to be the HMAC-SHA-1 of the Base-64 encoded policy using your secret key. Per these instructions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html#HTTPPOSTConstructingPolicySignature

Comment: just like this: string b64Policy = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(policyStr));

            byte[] b64Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AwsSecretKey);
            HMACSHA1 hmacSha1 = new HMACSHA1(b64Key);

            var c = Convert.ToBase64String(hmacSha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(b64Policy)));
            return c;

Answer (score 0):

Any conditions which are mentioned in the policy must also be in the form data. For example if you have a condition like

```
["starts-with", "x-amz-meta-myelement", ""]
```

Then you have to send that key. If the policy has constraints on content-type or key prefix these may also cause signature errors.

Comment: Hi @Jim, Here is the policy string: 
                          "\"Id\": \"Policyxxx\"," +
                          "\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\"," +
                          "\"Statement\": [" +
                            "{" +
                              "\"Sid\": \"Stmtxxx\"," +
                              "\"Action\": \"s3:*\"," +
                              "\"Effect\": \"Allow\"," +
                              "\"Resource\": \"arn:aws:s3:::bucketName/*\"," +
                              "\"Principal\": \"*\"" +
                            "}" +
                          "]"

Comment: I do not have a condition.. I have updated the question for more details of code.

Comment: That looks like an IAM Policy. The policies used with signed POST policies are slightly different. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html for some examples.

Comment: I changed and still getting the error :(((( here is code; { \"expiration\": \"2016-12-01T12:00:00.000Z\"," +
                          "\"conditions\": [" +
                          "{\"acl\": \"public-read\" }," +
                          "{\"bucket\": \"bucketname\" }," +
                          "[\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"\"]," +
                          "]" +
                        "}